# how to get the closest number using binary

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a code about checking whether numbers of the 2 arrays are the same or not, and if not then I want the closest(but not higher than) number. Since I am new to this, I don't really know how to do it.

If I try this:

```
int slice = 0;

for (int v = 0; v < m; v++)    // m is the length of the array a
{
    if (a[v] == Array.BinarySearch(b, a[v]))    // b is array b
    {
        slice += 5;
    }
}
```

If I try this, it seems like they are not the same even if I put the same numbers in the array to test this.

So basically the 2 questions are:

- What went wrong with this
- is there an easy way to get the closest number?

edit: I have been trying for some time myself and I am getting closer and the code looks like this:

```
int a=0;
        for (int v =0; v<m; v++)
        {
            if (b[v] >= c[~Array.BinarySearch(c, b[v]) - 1])
            {
                a+= b[v] - c[~Array.BinarySearch(c, b[v]) - 1];
            }

            else
            {
                a+= b[v];
            }
        }
```

So let's say in array b contain the following numbers: {4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and in c{2,3,4,5}.  I am going through all the numbers of b.So first 4: is 4 larger (or equal) than every number of c? the answer is yes so it is 4-4=0 and I add the 0 to the a. If there is a number smaller than every number of c, then I will just add that number to a. And I do this with every number. The problem now I have is: I get an out of range exception with equal to and smaller than(6 and lower), while larger than numbers(for example in this case: 6 or higher). Not sure why I get this problem any ideas?

Comment: By same arrays do you expect the arrays to have the same numbers in the same order or just the same numbers?  And if you can explain what "closest" number means, i.e. how many closest numbers you can get if lets say there are more then one numbers in the array that dont match

Comment: @Adi I mean in array b there may be the same numbers of array A and I want to get these numbers. If there aren't the same numbers in b then I want to get the closest number for example: if there is no 41 but there is 40, then it will give 40. I do it with a loop because I want to check all numbers at once

Comment: Can you provide a more elaborate example? Let's say A = [1,2,3,4,5] and B = [10,11,12,13,14,15]. What would you expect to be returned? Only 10 because it's the closest to 5? Or maybe all of them because they are each 10 away from the value at the same index?

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski I added the code since I have been busy trying to do this too. Let's take your example, if we look at B, the closest number of A is 5 so it is 10-5, 11-5, 12-5 etc.and I count all these numbers up.
if the number is smaller than every number of A, then I will just add that number up. I edited the code by the way maybe it is more clear